# Identify this insect - unknown location

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Please help identify this insect - genus, species and anything interesting about it.

(Part of this [old thread](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/64042/can-you-identify-these-insects?).)

[image]

[image]

Comment: The link is broken...

Comment: yes, the link isn't working. so i don't know if the link would have explained that this and your other question is about computer modeled insects. https://www.cgtrader.com/3d-models/animals/insect/insect-collection-vol-2 i'd think that's kind of important to know!

Answer (score 3):

It is a beetle of the genus *Eudicella*.
There are [several species](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eudicella) and some look quite similar, they are from tropical Africa.

[image]

Comment: which would you pick for species identification?

Comment: Eudicella gralli would be my guess but I do not know enough the group to be 100% sure.